# Using this. in angular does not work?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I created a simple button using angularjs. So, the code in HTML in the views looks like this :

```
    <div ng-controller="ButtonCtrl">
     <button ng-click="ButtonCtrl.setIndex(1)">Create another bidding query</button>
      <button ng-click="ButtonCtrl.setIndex(2)">Create another asking query</button>
        <form  ng-hide="ButtonCtrl.isSelected(1)">
         <h4>Filling The Bidding Form</h4>
         <fieldset class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" ></textarea>
         </fieldset>
         </form>
       <div>
```

And the ButtonCtrl is defined as follows in the controller.js

```
app.controller('ButtonCtrl', function($scope) {
   this.index=0;
   this.setIndex=function(setbutt){
       this.index=setbutt;
       };

    this.isSelected=function(checkbutt){
        return this.index===checkbutt;
    };
});
```

---

However, I do not get the expected behavior. The form does not hide itself when I click Create another bidding query button. When I use $scope function to replace the variable, such as $scope.index=0;, the program works.

I don't think the problem lies with using this.index because it works well for my other program. So, what is the exact problem?

Comment: I think you cannot use this and $scope in the same controller

Comment: That is a typo. I just updated my question.

Comment: Why do you want to use `this` instead of `$scope`?

Comment: I read the online tutorial in codeschool about angularjs. They use this. and do similar stuff. And my other function using this. actually works. So, I am really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to do this, you will have to use controllerAs syntax for using controllers in html.

```
<div ng-controller="ButtonCtrl as buttonCtrl">
 <button ng-click="buttonCtrl.setIndex(1)">Create another bidding query</button>
  <button ng-click="buttonCtrl.setIndex(2)">Create another asking query</button>
    <form  ng-hide="buttonCtrl.isSelected(1)">
     <h4>Filling The Bidding Form</h4>
     <fieldset class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" ></textarea>
     </fieldset>
     </form>
   <div>
```

And now, if use this in your controller instead of $scope, everything will work fine. See the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jain208/TFDY5/5/)

But personally I prefer using $scope inside controllers. It feels more natural to me, but that's just a personal choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to use your syntax `ButtonCtrl.setIndex(1)` you have to assign `this` to `$scope` in your controller like in the last line here:

```
app.controller('ButtonCtrl', function($scope) {
   this.index=0;
   this.setIndex=function(setbutt){
       this.index=setbutt;
       };

    this.isSelected=function(checkbutt){
        return this.index===checkbutt;
    };

    // set ButtonCtrl to the $scope
    $scope.ButtonCtrl = this;
});
```

Here is a good egghead.io video which explains it: [An Alternative Approach to Controllers](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-an-alternative-approach-to-controllers).

But as other answers already pointed out. This is not really idiomatic usage of AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to get your sample code working, there are a few things I notice.  First of all, *most* Angular code uses the `$scope` in place of this so that you can leverage the scope features that Angular provides.  In fact `$scope` is meant to be used *instead* of `this`. So, in terms of following the Angular way, the controller would look like this:

```
app.controller('ButtonCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.index=0;
   $scope.setIndex=function(setbutt){
       $scope.index=setbutt;
       };

    $scope.isSelected=function(checkbutt){
        return $scope.index===checkbutt;
    };
});
```

Further, once you have declared a controller (in the markup), you don't need to prefix each method call.  This is one of the benefits of using `$scope` correctly.  So, the markup would change to something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ButtonCtrl">
     <button ng-click="setIndex(1)">Create another bidding query</button>
     <button ng-click="setIndex(2)">Create another asking query</button>
         <form  ng-hide="isSelected(1)">
         <h4>Filling The Bidding Form</h4>
         <fieldset class="form-group">
             <textarea class="form-control" ></textarea>
         </fieldset>
     </form>
<div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how is $scope different from this.? Because this. method works well in other functions.

Comment: `$scope` is an angular provider that ties the lexical javascript scope to the DOM.  It is used the understand what changes and how to two-way bind back to  the DOM.  It also provides inheritance for by referencing `$parent` scopes that are declared in the DOM.  It is a fundamental part of how Angular works.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `$scope` or just variables in scope instead of `this`.

Like so:

```
$scope.index = 0;
$scope.setIndex = function(i) {
    $scope.index = i;
};
$scope.isSelected = function(i) {
    return ($scope.index === i);
};
```

(Or for example `var index = 0;` instead, if for some reason you don't want it in scope).

Comment: how is $scope different from this.? Because this. method works well in other functions.

Comment: `$scope` is an injected dependency, a scope created for the controller so it includes the prototypal inheritance as per usual. `this` is just a reference to the current controller. You should never really need to use `this` in an angular controller's main scope.